# inArray() conditional not triggering from proper values

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I have a function that limits input to numbers only, but I wanted to expand it so it would not be triggered on key inputs like arrows, backspace, and delete. I added these keycodes to an array, and am passing the event.keyCode to the function.

The keycode of, for example, backspace is 8, and even though it is in my array, it is not detecting it. Likewise, other keys (like letters) are not in the array, but the function is allowing them. When I console log, the integer of the keyCode seems to match.

Here is a fiddle of my code (that shows my console logs as text): http://jsfiddle.net/h36ST/

```
jQuery('input').on('keyup', function(e){
    onlyNumbers( jQuery(this), e.keyCode );
});

function onlyNumbers(oThis, keycode) {    
    allowedKeys = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46];

    if ( jQuery.inArray(keycode, allowedKeys) ) {
        return false;
    }

    jQuery(oThis).each(function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    });
}
```

Comment: [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns an index number, not a boolean. And, `0` is *falsy* while `-1` (not found) is *truthy*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery inArray returns index. If it is not there it will return -1.

```
if(jQuery.inArray(keycode, allowedKeys)!==-1){
    return;
}
```

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Why do you keep editing out `return false`? It doesn't block the keypress if you return nothing

Comment: Did not know that about inArray. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) returns an index.

> **Description**: Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

So your check should look like this:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(keycode, allowedKeys) !== -1){
    return false;
}
```

**OR**

Here is a nice operator `~` which works great with this kind of checks. Using this tilde operator your code will look like the following:

```
if(~jQuery.inArray(keycode, allowedKeys)){
    return false;
}
```

> The tilde reverses the order of the bits. The logic is ~N is -(N+1).

Here is the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h36ST/6/) of your code.

For more information about tilde (`~`) operator please refer [here](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/).

Comment: Thanks for the info on `~`. I will definitely read further on that!

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve your current issue and future issue which you will get when navigating using arrow keys in your textfield hope this will help

```
var allowedKeys = [8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105];
jQuery('input').on('keydown', function(e){

var result = jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, allowedKeys);
if ( result > -1 ) {
    jQuery('p.console').text(e.keyCode + ' is an acceptible non-numerical key.');
    return true;
} else {
    return false;        
}
```

});

[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/loboguxo/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the additional keyCodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use this.

```
if ( jQuery.inArray(keycode, allowedKeys)>-1 ) {
        jQuery('p.console').text(keycode + ' is an acceptible non-numerical key.');
        return false;
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/h36ST/4/)